# Accessing element nested in multiple div in a website

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to access value of nested element in a webpage.
As an example,
The web page contains many `div` and they are without any ID or CLASS.
So, I want value in  tag (`<a>Some Value</a>`)
which is nested in 3 div.

**NOTE -** There exist many such `<a>` nested in 3 `div`. 
But I require that `<a>` whose innerHTML starts from `http://`.
Any Feasibibility?

Comment: Why don't you add a class or id?

Comment: Ah....that's not my website.

Comment: Not your website? Are you iframeing? (may be illegal)

Comment: Nope. Just accessing value of element and using it in bash.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is "How do I access the content of the only anchor element that is nested inside three divs?" then you can do this:

```
var el = document.querySelector("div div div a"),
    value = el.innerHTML;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uPK94/

EDIT: If there can be multiple anchors and you want one "whose innerHTML starts from `http://`" you can do something like this:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("div div div a"),
    value;
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    if (anchors[i].innerHTML.indexOf("http://") === 0) {
        // anchors[i] is the element you're looking for
        value = anchors[i].innerHTML;
        // do something with value here
    }
}
```

The [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns the position of the first match of one string within another, so in your case you want it to be position 0. If you just wanted an anchor that had `http://` anywhere within its inner html you could use `anchors[i].innerHTML.indexOf("http://") != -1`.

See also:

- [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)
- [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector)

Comment: Ah...I recently found that the website contains such 2 more `<a>`.
which are nested in 3 div. So what can I do now?

Comment: Only difference between these `div` are their different `style` property, Is there any hope?

Comment: You need some way of uniquely identifying the one you want, even if just by number, e.g., if you know you always want the second instance that's easy enough. Regarding the `style` property, I think I would need to see your specific example before trying to code for it.

Comment: Is it possible to find next such element?
Whose innerHTML value starts form `http://`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var a = document.querySelector("div a");
```

Comment: Thought it said the `a` is nested in 3 div (as in the third div)